# persisting input box value entered by user

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am developing a `dash` application.I want the data, user has entered to be persisted if page gets refreshed or user switches between different pages.

I am first trying a basic example using an `input` box to persists the value entered by user and manually clicking on refresh button of browser.

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

dbc_css = (
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AnnMarieW/dash-bootstrap-templates@V1.0.2/dbc.min.css"
)
app = Dash(
    __name__,
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, dbc_css],
)

# With placeholder
ip1 = dbc.Input(placeholder="Please input count of persons", persistence=True)
ip2 = dbc.Input(placeholder="Please input count of persons", persistence=True, persistence_type="session")
ip3 = dbc.Input(placeholder="Please input count of persons", persistence=True, persistence_type="session", persisted_props="value")

# Without placeholder
ip4 = dbc.Input(persistence=True)
ip5 = dbc.Input(persistence=True, persistence_type="session")
ip6 = dbc.Input(persistence=True, persistence_type="session", persisted_props="value")

app.layout = dbc.Container([ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5, ip6])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8001", debug=True)
```

All the above cases failed to persist the value enter by the user. What I am missing?

Comment: See [ask]. Research enough. See [Basic Callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks). You didn't send anything to the server. How can the server remember field values?

Comment: Hi relent95, Sorry for confusion. When I specified the `id` for each components, it worked without `callback`. While browsing randomly for `plotly`  and `dash` blogs I read(long way back and if I recall correctly) if we did not specify `id` then dash will generate internally for you and I was under this impression which may not be the case in new versions. current I am using `2.9.2`.

Comment: The doc on persistence (https://dash.plotly.com/persistence) doesn't say outright that an explicit id is needed for a component with persistence, but I think it does suggest it. If it works when ids are specified, isn't that a straightforward solution?